# FXML displaying windows in other tabs

Tags: java, fxml

I have problem with displaying windows in my program. In the first window it is necessary to write in username and password and choose one option (Admin/Student). Then click button 'Login'. Additionaly I added also another label with message (if log data are good or not). But if I click this button, nothing happens. I don't know why.

LoginApp.java

```
    public class LoginController implements Initializable {

    LoginModel loginModel = new LoginModel();

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane ap;

    @FXML
    private Label loginstatus;

    @FXML
    private Label dbstatus;

    @FXML
    private TextField username;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField password;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<option> combobox;

    @FXML
    private Button loginbutton;

    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        if (this.loginModel.isDatabaseConnected()) {
            this.dbstatus.setText("Connected to Database");
        } else {
            this.dbstatus.setText("Not connected to Database");
        }
        this.combobox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(option.values()));
    }

    @FXML
    public void login(ActionEvent event) {
        //combobox.setEditable(false);
         try {
            if (this.loginModel.isLogin(this.username.getText(), this.password.getText(),
                    ((option) this.combobox.getValue()).toString())) {

                Stage stage = (Stage) this.loginbutton.getScene().getWindow();
                stage.close();
                switch (((option) this.combobox.getValue()).toString()) {
                    case "Student":
                        studentLogin();
                        break;
                    case "Admin":
                        adminLogin();
                        System.out.println("Dadasd");
                        break;
                }
            } if  (this.loginModel.isLogin(this.username.getText(), this.password.getText(),
                     ((option) this.combobox.getValue()).toString())) {
                this.loginstatus.setText("Connected");
            } else
             {
                this.loginstatus.setText("Denied");
             }
        } catch (Exception localException) {
        }

        try {
             this.username.setText("");
             this.password.setText("");
        }catch (Exception localException){

        }
    }

    public void studentLogin() {
        //combobox.setEditable(false);
        try {
            Stage userStage = new Stage();
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            Parent root = (Parent) loader.load(getClass().getResource("/students/studentFXML.fxml").openStream());

            StudentController studentController = (StudentController) loader.getController();

            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            userStage.setScene(scene);
            userStage.setTitle("Student Board");
            userStage.setResizable(false);
            userStage.show();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void adminLogin() {
        //combobox.setEditable(false);
        try {
            Stage adminStage = new Stage();
            FXMLLoader adminLoader = new FXMLLoader();
            Pane adminroot = (Pane) adminLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/admin/tabs/admin.fxml").openStream());

            AdminController adminController = (AdminController) adminLoader.getController();

            Scene scene = new Scene(adminroot);
            adminStage.setScene(scene);
            adminStage.setTitle("Admin Board");
            adminStage.setResizable(false);
            adminStage.show();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

login.fxml

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="350.0" prefWidth="350.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="loginapp.LoginController">
    <children>
        <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="86.0" text="DB status" />
        <Label fx:id="dbstatus" layoutX="101.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="216.0" />
        <Label fx:id="loginstatus" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="217.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="79.0" />
        <TextField fx:id="username" layoutX="101.0" layoutY="79.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="216.0" promptText="user name" />
        <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="83.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="79.0" text="UserName" />
        <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="124.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="79.0" text="Password" />
        <PasswordField fx:id="password" layoutX="101.0" layoutY="120.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="216.0" promptText="password" />
        <ComboBox fx:id="combobox" layoutX="101.0" layoutY="169.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="216.0" promptText="Admin/Student" />
        <Button fx:id="loginbutton" layoutX="100.0" layoutY="213.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#login" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="216.0" text="Login" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

StudentController.java

```
public class StudentController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private TextField firstname;

    @FXML
    private TextField lastname;

    @FXML
    private TextField email;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker dob;

    @FXML
    private TableView<StudentData> studenttable;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<StudentData, String> firstnamecolumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<StudentData, String> lastnamecolumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<StudentData, String> emailcolumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<StudentData, String> dobcolumn;

    private ObservableList<StudentData> data;
    private dbConnection dc;

    private String sql = "SELECT * FROM students";

    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        this.dc = new dbConnection();
    }

    @FXML
    private void loadStudentData(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException {
        try {

            Connection conn = dbConnection.getConnection();
            this.data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

            ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {
                this.data.add(new StudentData(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3),
                        rs.getString(4)));        }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error : " + ex);
        }

        this.firstnamecolumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<StudentData, String>("firstName"));
        this.lastnamecolumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<StudentData, String>("lastName"));
        this.emailcolumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<StudentData, String>("email"));
        this.dobcolumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<StudentData, String>("DOB"));

        this.studenttable.setItems(null);
        this.studenttable.setItems(this.data);
    }

    @FXML
    private void addStudent (ActionEvent event) {
        String sqlAdd = "INSERT INTO students (firstName, lastName, email, DOB) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

        try {
            Connection conn = dbConnection.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlAdd);

            stmt.setString(2, this.firstname.getText());
            stmt.setString(3, this.lastname.getText());
            stmt.setString(4, this.email.getText());
            stmt.setString(5, this.dob.getEditor().getText());

            stmt.execute();
            stmt.close();

        }catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error :" + ex);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void clearFields(ActionEvent event) {
        this.firstname.setText("");
        this.lastname.setText("");
        this.email.setText("");
        this.dob.setValue(null);
    }
}
```

studentFXML.fxml

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="360.0"
            prefWidth="640.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            fx:controller="students.StudentController">
    <children>
        <TabPane prefHeight="360.0" prefWidth="640.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
            <tabs>
                <Tab text="Student">
                    <content>
                        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="360.0" prefWidth="640.0">
                            <children>
                                <HBox layoutX="156.0" prefHeight="330.0" prefWidth="490.0">
                                    <children>
                                        <TableView fx:id="studenttable" prefHeight="330.0" prefWidth="490.0">
                                            <columns>
                                                <TableColumn fx:id="idcolumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="ID"/>
                                                <TableColumn fx:id="firstnamecolumn" prefWidth="106.0"
                                                             text="First Name"/>
                                                <TableColumn fx:id="lastnamecolumn" prefWidth="112.0" text="Last Name"/>
                                                <TableColumn fx:id="emailcolumn" prefWidth="108.0" text="Email"/>
                                                <TableColumn fx:id="dobcolumn" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="82.0"
                                                             text="DOB"/>
                                            </columns>
                                        </TableView>
                                    </children>
                                </HBox>
                                <VBox prefHeight="337.0" prefWidth="159.0">
                                    <children>
                                        <Label prefHeight="19.0" prefWidth="160.0" text="Add student">
                                            <padding>
                                                <Insets left="10.0"/>
                                            </padding>
                                            <VBox.margin>
                                                <Insets/>
                                            </VBox.margin>
                                        </Label>
                                        <TextField fx:id="id">
                                            <VBox.margin>
                                                <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0"/>
                                            </VBox.margin>
                                        </TextField>
                                        <TextField fx:id="firstname" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="29.0"
                                                   promptText="First Name">
                                            <VBox.margin>
                                                <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0"/>
                                            </VBox.margin>
                                        </TextField>
                                        <TextField fx:id="lastname" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="54.0"
                                                   promptText="Last Name">
                                            <VBox.margin>
                                                <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0"/>
                                            </VBox.margin>
                                        </TextField>
                                        <TextField fx:id="email" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="54.0" promptText="Email">
                                            <VBox.margin>
                                                <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0"/>
                                            </VBox.margin>
                                        </TextField>
                                        <DatePicker fx:id="dob" prefWidth="200.0">
                                            <VBox.margin>
                                                <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0"/>
                                            </VBox.margin>
                                        </DatePicker>
                                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addStudent" prefHeight="17.0"
                                                prefWidth="140.0" text="Add Data">
                                            <VBox.margin>
                                                <Insets left="10.0"/>
                                            </VBox.margin>
                                        </Button>
                                        <Button layoutX="20.0" layoutY="164.0" mnemonicParsing="false"
                                                onAction="#clearFields" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="140.0"
                                                text="Clear Form">
                                            <VBox.margin>
                                                <Insets left="10.0"/>
                                            </VBox.margin>
                                        </Button>
                                        <Button layoutX="20.0" layoutY="189.0" mnemonicParsing="false"
                                                onAction="#loadStudentData" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="140.0"
                                                text="Load Form">
                                            <VBox.margin>
                                                <Insets left="10.0"/>
                                            </VBox.margin>
                                        </Button>
                                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="152.0"
                                                text="Delete Data">
                                            <VBox.margin>
                                                <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0"/>
                                            </VBox.margin>
                                        </Button>
                                    </children>
                                </VBox>
                            </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                    </content>
                </Tab>
            </tabs>
        </TabPane>
    </children>
```

option.java

```
public enum option {
    Admin, Student;

    private option() {}

    public String value() {

        return name();
        }

        public static option fromvalue (String v) {

        return valueOf(v);
        }
}
```

Comment: can you add your option class

Comment: I think its because `this.loginModel.isLogin(this.username.getText(), this.password.getText(),((option) this.combobox.getValue()).toString())` alway returns false. Please re check implementation of `loginModel.isLogin()`